# What would the world be like today if the Germany had won WWI?

Tags: culture, politics, alternate-history, history

I'm trying to create a world set in our current time but where the only difference is that 100 years prior the Central Powers won WWI. I'm curious how the geopolitics of the world would change.

In an effort to make this question less broad, what would be the single biggest change in the geopolitical make up of the world if Germany had won WWI?

Comment: The scope of this question might be considered too broad and closed, but I'm not sure an effective way to break this apart.

Comment: @NexTerren Breaking the question apart by the bullet points would be a good place to start, but some of those are also too broad, I think.  Can they be further subdivided?

Comment: Also welcome to World Building, otteheng! This is an interesting question, but questions of such scope typically receive poor quality answers if they receive answers at all. Thus we have a policy of a strong-arm tactic of stopping such questions. If you can break up the question (edit this one or post a new one) you'll get much higher quality feedback. Don't let his scare you off. :)

Comment: Harry Turtledove's series of alternate history where the South wins the Civil War also has Germany/Central Powers win WWI. You could check those books out to see what Europe may look like at the least. Also, perhaps you should imagine for you question: How did Germany win? Also, I know one US President strongly favored growing ties between Britain- if he wasn't president would the US have sided with Germany?

Comment: @NexTerren Thanks for the feedback. Would concentrating on just one of the bullet points and going into more detail there help?

Comment: Not having WWI at all might have prevented WWII but Germany winning it would have led to a later clash of British Empire and German Empire as British policy was to prevent a single power taking effective control in Europe.